# Options to replace deprecated DirectSound

Tags: c++, visual-c++, directx, directsound

I have a code which implements DirectSound8. MSFT states in its website that this library has been deprecated. So, what are my options if I updated this code provided that I maintain the windows platform. If I switched to Linux, what are the options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Windows and Xbox One, the replacement for the DirectSound API for playback/3D positional audio is [XAudio2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/05/15/learning-xaudio2/).

There are numerous 3rd party audio solutions available. [This blog post](https://annesoaudio.com/2016/06/12/audio-middleware-comparion-wwisefmodfabric/) discusses a number of them. They are usually cross-platform, and on Windows they make use of WASAPI for communication with the audio hardware.

Comment: Chuck, in simple what is the most important feature that XAudio2 brings in when compared to DirectSound ?

Comment: This is covered in detail on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee415813.aspx). Also DirectSound is legacy and on Windows Vista or later has a number of older features disabled. Probably the biggest single difference is that in DirectSound you have to copy all your sound data into system-provided buffers, while XAudio2 will read directly out of your application buffers for more efficient mixing & playback.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. It's pretty insightful to know in advance the rationale for using this low-level API.

Comment: I would recommend using FFMPEG instead as it supports other platforms too

Comment: DirectSound, XAudio2, FMOD, WWise, etc. are for real-time audio mixing which is what games use, with various effects like 3D head-relative position and reverb. ``FFMPEG`` is intended for recording, conversion, and streaming which is not quite the same thing. On Windows platform, ``FFMPEG`` is more like Media Foundation.